# How to highlight region over region

Tags: syntax-highlighting

Let's think we are going to render html file. We highlight `<a>` and `<img>` tags, so `a` and `img` will be highlighted as Keywords. We assume `<a>` accepts attribute `href` but not `src`, while `<img>` accepts attribute `src` not `href`. So in `<a href="place1" src="place2">`, `href` will be highlighted as, let's say, Identifier, while `src` will not be highlighted; while in `<img href="place1" src="place2">`, `src` will be highlighted but `href` will not be highlighted. Is there a way of implementing this via `syntax region` or `syntax match`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with the `:syntax` command's `contains`, `containedin`, and `contained` keywords. See `:help syn-contains`, `:help syn-containedin` and `:help :syn-contained` for the documentation on these, but briefly, the technique is to

1. Use either `contains` to allow an outer group to contain an inner group or `containedin` to allow an inner group to be contained within an outer group,
2. Use `contained` to only activate an inner group when it is contained within another.

Here a basic example of one way to achieve what you describe in your question (with extremely simplified regular expressions—the point is to demonstrate the use of the `containedin` and `contained` keywords, not the matching of tags. If you need help with that, maybe take a look at Vim's included HTML syntax file: `e $VIMRUNTIME/syntax/html.vim`).

```
syntax match myAnchorTag /<a.*a>/
syntax match myImgTag /<img.*img>/

syntax match myHrefAttribute containedin=myAnchorTag contained /href/
syntax match mySrcAttribute containedin=myImgTag contained /src/

highlight link myHrefAttribute Identifier
highlight link mySrcAttribute Identifier
```